# Recursive Object mapping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion

I am trying to map an object from another object in JavaScript. Like

```
var requestObj = {
  id: "",
  name: "",
  age: "",
  obj: {
    id: ""
  }
};

var processedObj = {
  id: 10,
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 20,
  family: true,
  obj: {
    id: 100,
    text: "Obj Desc"
  }
};
```

If I call a method like

```
format(requestObj, processedObj);
```

I need to get the output as

```
{
  id: 10,
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 20,
  obj: {
    id: 100
  }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uhg436u/3/)

Everything is working fine if there are no inner objects. I created a recursive method but it is not working as expected. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things needs correction in your original code, when you were calling `format()` function recursively you were not assigning the results returned from the function. Also arguments to `format()` function seemed incorrect to me.

I've modified your code a bit. And it outputs your desired format.

```js
var requestObj = {
  id: "",
  name: "",
  age: "",
  obj: {
    id: ""
  }
};

var processedObj = {
  id: 10,
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 20,
  family: true,
  obj: {
    id: 100,
    text: "Obj Desc"
  }
};


format(requestObj, processedObj);

function format(requestObj, processedObj) {
  for (var keys in processedObj) {

    if (requestObj.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
      if (typeof processedObj[keys] == 'object') {
        requestObj[keys] = format(requestObj[keys], processedObj[keys]);
      } else {
        requestObj[keys] = processedObj[keys];
      }


    }
  }
  return requestObj;
}

console.log(requestObj)
```